# I have lived/I have been living or I lived the difference between BrE and AmE

Tags: present-tense

These sentences are written by a native speaker. Each sentence is correct, but I have also been told that I have been living/working here for X years" means  that the person
still is so it is not appropriate if I am   moving out or leaving the job today. Is this the difference between AmE and BrE? These are clearly different opinions.

1. "I'm moving to a new house today. I lived here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

2."I'm moving to a new house today. I have lived here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

3. "I'm moving to a new house today. I have been living here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

Comment: If "I have been living/working here for X years" implies that you still are, so it is not appropriate if you are moving out or leaving the job today. " Then why do another native speaker (BrE speaker) uses present perfect continuous and present perfect with "today" in #2 and #3  if the speaker is no longer living/working there?

Comment: I think I was the one who said that. I can only say that, _to me_, that is what it implies.

Comment: So, as a non-native speaker, I will take both opinions into account and remember that some native speakers use "today" only with present perfect continuous and present perfect while others with past simple. But if I am not using the word "today" and say before  literary leaving the office building, the classroom after the final lesson and my house *forever* can I use  "I have been working/I have worked/worked here for ten years,  I have been studying/studied/have studied English for two months,  I have been living//have lived/lived here for twenty years is either tense correct?

Comment: The word "here" in sentences #2 and #3 means you are in the house, or in its garden or front yard. In sentence #1 it suggests  you are outside, taking a last look at the place. You are already thinking of yourself as an ex-resident.

Comment: So only sentence 1 can express what I really want to express that I am taking a last look at the house. I thought it's past simple not the word *here* suggests that I am outside taking a last look at it. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, regarding this explanation: "I think I was the one who said that. I can only say that, to me, that is what it implies. " Would you also not use present perfect in the situation you were talking about with *today* if I am leaving the place? I am asking about the original sentences.

Comment: I would use the present perfect until I had actually left the house for the last time.

Comment: I see. Thank you.